# Accessing dictionary keys with invalid identifiers in django templates

Tags: django, django-templates

Say I have a dictionary that looks like:

```
settings = {
    'info:ip': '127.0.0.1',
    'info:browser': 'chrome'
}
```

I'd like to access these items in a django template, as in:

```
The IP is {{settings.info:ip}} .
```

"info:ip" is a valid dictionary key but not a valid variable name or django template name I can't seem to get to it.

I realize I could use a different dictionary key, but it's inconvenient for several reasons. Any other way to get at that dictionary key in my template?

Answer (score 1):

*update*
Or a general template tag to take advantage that any literal string is allowed

```
from django.template import Template, Context, defaulttags

@defaulttags.register.simple_tag
def getter(d, key):
    return d.get(key, '')

>>> Template('{% getter settings "x:y" %}').render(Context({"settings":{'x:y':1}}))
1
```

---

What about write a filter to work around it then

```
from django.template import Template, Context, defaultfilters

@defaultfilters.register.filter(is_save=True)
def tiny_replace(value):
    r = {}
    for k, v in value.iteritems():
        r[k.replace(':', '_')] = v
    return r

>>> Template('{% with s=settings|tiny_replace %}{{s.x_y}}{% endwith %}').render(Context({"settings":{'x:y':1}}))
1
```

Answer (score 0):

What about this

```
settings = {
    'info': {
        'ip': '127.0.0.1',
        'browser': 'chrome'
    }
}
```

and use it like `{{ settings.info.ip }}`?
Is that an option for you?